# adding td dynamically does not expand by colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-tables

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xzfb/)

On click on arrow down image, i am displaying the next tr (initially hidden) which have a td with colspan 5 and table inside it.

My question is why the td is not expanding to the full row, as i have specified colspan=5

```
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-chevron-down').click(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").next().removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't you change the show class? It's a bootstrap class, used to display elements so it set display:block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, I've not looked into it that much but this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/57d3M/1/.

```
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-chevron-down').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr')
        .next('tr')
        .toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

because your `.show` bootstrap css rule contains following

```
.show{
    display:block; !important;
}
```

You can overwrite it with custom CSS-rule for the row like this:

```
.show{
    display:table-row !important;
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xzfb/4/)

Comment: @user2847429 You can overwrite bootstrap class `.show` with the CSS as i mentioned in the answer!

Comment: @C-link OP is using bootstrap, Check it again!

Answer (score 1):

The class show is causing the trouble. Removing the class solves the problem.

HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <caption>Order History</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Transaction ID</th>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>View/Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td>T00580901</td>
                <td>10 May'14<br />10:10 am</td>
                <td>Delivered</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none">
                <td colspan="5">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>S.No</th>
                                <th>Dish Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Total Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1.</td>
                                <td>South Indian Meal</td>
                                <td>Rs. 100</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Rs. 200</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-chevron-down').click(function () {
        console.log("hi");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
    });
});
```

See the update fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/2Xzfb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Set table-layout to fixed:

```
.table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 400px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xzfb/3/)

Comment: definitely not the solution for me. i want table to be my container width. tried assigning width: 100% did not work for me